# Child thread in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, multithreading

Would it be possible to create a new [thread](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php) in a Wordpress Plugin to do some super lightweight async work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async tasks are supposed to be done using the wp_schedule_event function.
It schedules an event in a future time thats activated by the wp-cron system.

For a single async task you should use the wp_schedule_single_event function like this:

```
wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'my_new_event' );
```

You pass in the current time, and the action defined for the task.

This is fine for normal async tasks that wordpress needs.

If you however need a real async thread to process something,its better to look into the [WP Background Processing Library](https://deliciousbrains.com/background-processing-wordpress/) by Ashley Rich. Its pretty good.